# PHPExcel- cannot loop through the array

Tags: php, arrays, phpexcel

I'm unable to loop through the array I received from an excel sheet.

```php
//  Read a row of data into an array
for ($row = 0; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 

    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A'.$row.':'.$highestColumn.$row,NULL,TRUE,FALSE);

    for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
        $cella = strtoupper($rowData[$row][$i]);
        //$cellb = strtoupper($rowData[0][1]);
        //$cellc = $rowData[0][2];
        //$celld = $rowData[0][3];
        echo $cella;
    }

}
```

This gives an error:

> Severity: Notice Message: Undefined offset: 1

If i use

```
$cella = strtoupper($rowData[0][0])
```

it prints properly. Why is it so?

Comment: That's because (may be) `$rowData[0]` array has only one element. Do `var_dump($rowData[0]);` to see all keys and the corresponding values.

Comment: In MS Excel, row numbers start at 1, not at 0

Comment: I would `dd($sheet)` to better understand the result array.

Comment: I tried some other option and solved the problem :-)